# Array doesn't log anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I have a problem logging an array. In my discord bot, I retrieve all of the server ids that my bot is in. My bot has a different language for every server (the default is English) so I need to keep track of that so I can send a message with the language that is saved. Instead of requesting the database, I wanted to build a little cache (on bot enable retrieve every server's language). But the problem is that even if I insert, push the object to the array, the array is still empty (i console.loged it). So the question is... HOW?

```
    serverIdd.forEach(async (server) => {
    
        let serv = await find("serverList", parseFloat(server));

        if (!serv[0]) {

            await insertServer(server, defLang); // returns promise 
            
            serverLangCache.push({ id: server, lang: defLang })
            

        } else {
            console.log(server + " is already in!");
            let lang = serv[0].lang;
            
            serverLangCache.push({ id: server, lang: lang})

        }
        
        
        
    });
    console.log(serverLangCache); <-- this executes before the foreach does
    //Logs:

   //[] <-- the console log logs an empty array
   //436072156871262200 saved to serverList <-- now the foreach is going off 
   //490471288255676400 saved to serverList <-- now the foreach is going off
```

Comment: I don't think `.join()` does what you think it does. Did you mean `.push()` instead?

Comment: Okay something weird happened. I used push, and when the servers are in the data base it logs https://pastebin.com/LWdXdhBS but if the server isn't in the array it doesn't even log the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woo! Finally, we got it! (Posting if ever anyone has the same problem)

So the final code looks like this:

```
client.once('ready', async() => {
    

    let index = 0;
    console.log("ready!");
    

    let serverIdd = await client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.id);
    let defLang = "en";
        
        let serverLangCache = [];
        debugger;
        
            
        for (let i = 0; i < serverIdd.length; i++) {
            
            
            let serv = await find("serverList", parseFloat(serverIdd[i]));
    
            if (!serv[0]) {
    
                insertServer(serverIdd[i], defLang)
                
                serverLangCache.push({ id: serverIdd[i], lang: defLang })

                
                
                
    
            } else {
                console.log(serverIdd[i] + " is already in!");
                let lang = serv[0].lang;
                
                serverLangCache.push({ id: serverIdd[i], lang: lang})
    
            }
        
            
            
        
        
        
            
        }
            
        console.log(serverLangCache);
        

    
    

    let act = ["b!help", `Server count: {count}!`, "braumobot.site", "Work in progress, bot disabled"];
    setInterval( () => {
        config = readConfigFile();
        if (index != 4) {

            client.user.setActivity(act[index].replace("{count}", config.servers.length), {
                type: "PLAYING",
            })
            index++;
        } else {
            index = 0;
        }




    }, 5000);



    





});
});
```

So you see, the problem wasn't even in the code that was originally in the post. The problem was the

```
function insertServer(serverId, langu){

    
        
    
        
    let srv = new Server({
        id: serverId,
        lang: langu
    });
        
    
    srv.save().then((s)=>{
        console.log(s.id + "saved to serverList");

    })
    


    


}
```

function. I made it async and thought that it might help but then realized that it doesn't need to be async. I removed the await and removed the promise in the function and it works like a charm! (THANK YOU VS CODE DEBUGGER <3)

Answer (score 0):

There're some problems you should avoid to make things run as expected:

1. Shouldn't use array for caching, use Map instead:

```
const serverLangCache = new Map();
...
serverLangCache.set(server, { id: server, lang });
console.log(Array.from(serverLangCache.values()));
```

2. Don't use `.forEach` for running async tasks, it doesn't work as you expected, use normal loop or `for...of` instead.

Comment: Okay but there's another problem. I used the for of loop but it loops over every id in the array and it gets stuck when it needs to save it to the db (it saves it but the rest isn't going off) https://pastebin.com/EgSHvu9b Look at the end of the pastebin

Comment: And why should I use a map instead of an array?

Comment: There maybe exception thrown, using async function for a callback is not recommended since it can caused unhandled promises rejection, you should handle error for further debugging: `client.once('ready', (async() => {...})().catch(e => {console.log(e.message)});`

Comment: since you're calling it a cache, you have to deal with duplication/existed item, `map` solves it for you way more better than `array`.

Comment: Well now it fricked up https://pastebin.com/tfUePnYB the logs are on the bottom of the pastebin

Comment: Okay maybe this will help, everytime I compiled I had the client ready in `mongoose.connection.once` and sometimes only `"conn"` console.logged (like the client ready never executed) and sometimes it was working fine, i just wanted to make sure that i wont have an error in my `find()` function. Maybe that's why it broke. [Link](https://pastebin.com/Zck1uxUD)

Comment: Okay! We got it working, thank you tho for letting me know that using the foreach wasn't a great idea. Thank you very much again!